# sending bytes as pdf

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications

**EDIT: The data I wanna send is in an rds. I fetch that into an output stream and then try to send it over as a pdf to the user.**

The file gets generated but on opening the browser shows 'Failed to load PDF document.'
I have read that setting the ContentType to "application/pdf" helps but it does not in my case. The code is given below

```
byte[] b = generateFileService
            .getDeviceHumidityRecordByPeriod(deviceIdValue, parseUnixTimestamp(startTime), parseUnixTimestamp(endTime));
    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
    output.write(b);
    output.close();

    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

if I change the file name to test.csv and then use content type as txt/plain, it works perfectly and a csv file is written.

Comment: The content type only describes the content. The browser won't be able to render a PDF unless you're actually sending PDF content. Changing the content type and filename is not sufficient.

Comment: Hi @hoipolloi, thanks for your reply. I have edited the question. I don't have a pdf file, just some data in the database that I want to allow the user to download as a pdf and csv. The csv works.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use a PDF library for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510560/pdf-library-for-java

Answer (score 0):

I used Apache PDFBox to write data into a pdf file. The page offset needs to be tracked to add pages dynamically. Then you can convert the pdf into bytes and send it to the client by specifying response.setContentType("application/pdf") and response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf")